# jquery: remove table row while iterating through table rows

Tags: jquery, html, tablerow

`#exceptions` is a html table. I try to run the code below, but it doesn't remove the table row.

```
$('#exceptions').find('tr').each(function(){
    var flag=false;
    var val = 'excalibur';
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == val) 
            flag = true;
    });
    if(flag)
        $(this).parent().remove($(this));
});
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).remove()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable flag ever evaluates to true, I think you may just want to do...

```
$(this).remove();
```

instead of...

```
$(this).parent().remove($(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `flag` ever turn `true`? Try `alert`ing it. There's also a less complicated way of removing an element:

```
if(flag)
    $(this).remove();
```